# How to add a dynamic query string to a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyone who can help me?

How to add a dynamic query string to the link containing a randomly generated, 10 digit number (in a format like www.placeholder.com/xyz.pdf?r=random_number for circumventing browser caching).

Thank!

Comment: Please post what you have tried and explain how it does not work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is duplicate question

Comment: Apart from being incorrectly formated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent caching you could also just use the current timestamp instead of random number.

The following code snippet finds every link on the page containing "pdf" and adds either ?r={timestamp} or &r={timestamp}.

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime(),
links = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*=pdf]");
for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; ++i) {
    links[i].href += [/\?/.test(links[i].href) ? '&' : '?', "r=", timestamp].join("");
}
```

But I'm almost sure you could achieve it in a better way, for example by disabling the browser caching in the browser's developer tools (if it's for debugging purposes)

Comment: Great, it's working great. Many thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, Go to http://skillcram.com/JS.htm and click on 
the link DynamicLink for working example:

function dynamicLink()
    {

```
    var rand = Math.random();
    var randNum = Math.floor(rand * 10000000000);
    window.open("http://www.dynamicLinkTest.com/xyz.pdf?r="+randNum);
}
```